# Finding p in Legendre's symbol

Tags: elementary-number-theory

The question is as follows: Find all odd primes $p$ such that $$\left(\frac 7p\right)=1$$  If the Legendre's symbol is flipped by quadratic reciprocity, we get $\left(\frac p7\right)=\pm1$. In this case, $p\equiv \pm1, \pm2, \pm3\pmod7.$ Is this correct?

Comment: Do a reality check: ***every prime other than 7*** is equal to one of $1,2,3,4,5,6\bmod 7$. Do you think $\left(\frac{7}{p}\right)=1$ for *every prime $p$ other than 7*?

Answer (score 1):

No, if you flip it by quadratic reciprocity, it will be $+1$ if $p\equiv1 \pmod 4$ and $-1$ if $p=1 \pmod 4$ . So you will have two cases and will have to go mod $24$.

Comment: @Paradox101: Have you looked at the statement of quadratic reciprocity?